# Pegar dados do servidor sem refresh

Tags: php, java, ajax

Tenho um script com uma lista de usuários amigos e ao lado uma box chat.

[image: 4CHAT]

Quando o usuário clicar em um de seus amigos na lista os dados dele `ID` & `NOME` são enviados para uma função `openWidChat(de,para,nome)` que recebe o `ID` do usuário logado, `ID` do usuário clicado na lista e o nome do outro.

Os dados vão direto para essa script:

```
function openWidChat(de,para,nome) {
        var url_s = $("#url_s").val();
        $("label#boxC input").val('');
        $("label#boxC input").attr('user-de',de);
        $("label#boxC input").attr('user-para',para);

        $("._5chat").attr('id','chat_'+para);
        $("#m_form-header div.load4Box").fadeIn(400).html('<div class="maxWid_16"><img src="'+ url_s +'/themes/4space/images/load/loadLikesW.gif" alt="" width="16" height="16"></div>');
            $.ajax({
                url: url_s +"/demo/chat/chat.php",
                data:'de='+de+'&para='+para+'&url_s='+url_s,
                type: "POST",
                cache: false,
                success : function(html){
                    $("label#boxC ").removeClass("bord-b_in");
                    $("#m_form-header div.nameUserBox").html(nome);
                    $("label#boxC input").removeAttr('disabled');
                    $("label#boxC input").attr("placeholder", "Escreva uma mensagem...");

                    $("#m_form-header div.load4Box").html('<a id="dLabel" data-target="#" href="http://example.com" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i></a><ul class="menDroo-clear dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">Limpar converça</ul>');
                    $("#mensChat div#chat_"+para).html(html);
                    $("._5chat").scrollTop($("._5chat")[0].scrollHeight);
                }
        });
}
```

E após receber os dados na box carregar as mensagens trocadas entre os usuários, porém tem que ficar dando refresh de tempo em tempo pra ficar em tempo real com as mensagens que vai receber.

O fato é que eu consigo fazer isso e dar o refresh através do ajax e setInterval:

```
function setLoop(de,para,nome) {
   var url_s = $("#url_s").val();
   $("._5chat").attr('id','chat_'+para);
   setInterval(function() {
       $("#mensChat div#chat_"+para).load(url_s+"/demo/chat/test.php?="+de+"&p="+para+"&url_s="+url_s);
   }, 1000);
}
```

Porém quando eu clicar em outro usuário da lista, *eu acredito*, que o `setInterval` está como se fosse armazenando o `setInterval` anterior e fica indo e voltando entre os chats de um usuário e outro e se clicar em outro aumenta o vai e vem e acrescenta a conversa do terceiro.

Já tentei usar o `clearInterval`, mas não deu certo, ou não consegui fazer com que funcionasse corretamente.

O que preciso é que ele receba a conversa por vez e cancele a conversa anterior após clicar em um outro amigo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você só precisa salvar o `setInterval` numa variável global. Logo em seguida, bem antes da sua função `setInterval`, você reseta seu intervalo com `clearInterval(variavel_global);`. Por último, sobrescreva a variável global com o novo `setInterval`.

Se ficou confuso, dê uma olhada abaixo.

**Versão normal com variável global (s/ problema)**

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/felipe_douradinho/dvchLpjj/2/)

```
var loop = setInterval;

function setLoop(de, para, nome) {
   //var url_s = $("#url_s").val();
   //$("._5chat").attr('id','chat_'+para);

   clearInterval(loop);
   loop = setInterval(function() {
       //$("#mensChat div#chat_"+para).load(url_s+"/demo/chat/test.php?="+de+"&p="+para+"&url_s="+url_s);
       console.log('mensagem: de => '+de+' | para '+para+' | nome => '+nome+'');
   }, 1000);
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.usuario').click(function() {
        setLoop('de', 'para #id' + $(this).attr('id'), 'nome');
    });
});
```

**Versão sem variável global (c/ problema)**

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/felipe_douradinho/dvchLpjj/3/)

```
function setLoop(de, para, nome) {
   //var url_s = $("#url_s").val();
   //$("._5chat").attr('id','chat_'+para);

   setInterval(function() {
       //$("#mensChat div#chat_"+para).load(url_s+"/demo/chat/test.php?="+de+"&p="+para+"&url_s="+url_s);
       console.log('mensagem: de => '+de+' | para '+para+' | nome => '+nome+'');
   }, 1000);
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.usuario').click(function() {
        setLoop('de', 'para #id' + $(this).attr('id'), 'nome');
    });
});
```

Comment: Mano obrigado mesmo... realmente o código global funfo, da as vezes um vai e vem mas ta legal vou tentar aperfeiçoar...
**WHATSAPP** - (81) - 99877-7659

Comment: Opa, eu imaginei que desse mesmo, pois o ajax ainda pode estar terminando de receber a resposta quando alguém clica num usuário... Eu colocaria a requisição do ajax como assíncrona neste caso (opção `async`)..se resolveu, por favor, marque a resposta como válida :D